# Hadoop SequenceFile size

Tags: java, hadoop, size, mahout, sequencefile

I'm creating a HashMap of key value pairs of a Hadoop Vector that is stored inside a SequenceFile. For efficiency purposes I want to know how long the Vector of key value pairs is so that I can initialise the HashMap with the proper size.

I have used Mahout's `seqdumper` and it appends a Count at the end of each dumped Vector. I have looked into its code but it used a simple iterative counter (for each row `counter++`) and thus isn't what I'm looking for.

Also [`SequenceFile.MetaData`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.Metadata.html) looked promising, so I looked into it. But the debugger shows that it contains no entries.

Is there some other way to quickly get something like a `.size()` method for a Hadoop Vector inside a SequenceFile?

**Edit:** Here is the output of seqdumper of what I'm turning into a Map. Specifically, each Key Value pair is a IntWritable / NamedVector pair. I wish to create a mapping from the key number to the URI String. There are in total 46599 keys value pairs,as appended by `seqdumper` at the end of the file.

```
Input Path: luceneVectors
Key class: class org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable Value Class: class org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable
Key: 0: Value: http://data.artsholland.com/production/73adae07-78c6-4180-93a4-34802090b5f1:{22118:0.18376858424635545,20381:0.40144184831236357,53753:0.2605347739121081,51569:0.2578896608715637,21930:0.2277873354603338,63035:0.27765920678967304,36979:0.2709104089668357,68351:0.15788776111071648,19436:0.2988119565549418,17991:0.12435264873296237,10356:0.3276902508762499,3410:0.27239123806574506,62942:0.18961849195965186,32527:0.24827631823639457,69909:0.11723303910369048,19832:0.2138117449778048}
Key: 1: Value: http://data.artsholland.com/production/c9fcc92b-18bb-4bfb-af52-380707f8d0d7:{41167:0.07191351238480857,61391:0.07496730342220936,[...]
[...],19156:0.0687215948604245}
Count: 46599
```

Comment: Can you give more information about the Key / Value writables types used in your sequence file?

Comment: I've added a snippet with what I'm trying to turn into a Map.

Comment: Read through it and count your rows, there is no other way.

Comment: I see. So be it then.
I'm still open for answers if anyone has them.

Comment: Is there a way to add entries to the SequenceFile.MetaData after the SequenceFile is written? Because then you could add the amount of entries written into the MetaData.

Answer (score 1):

No sure, that my answer will be useful, nevertheless if you need to know how many keys in seq file, you can use MapFile instead of SequenceFile. 
Knowing indexInterval you can estimate number of keys by reading key file. If you set indexInterval relatively large, you can maintain small index file and still estimate number of keys.
As additional bonus, you get sampling of you keys, which can help you to optimize further.

more details about different versions of SequenceFiles can be found here http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/hadoop-io-sequence-map-set-array-bloommap-files/

Comment: So when you have the index of the SequenceFile and the indexinterval you can estimate that the maximum amount of keys is `indexInterval * indexEntries`. This isn't accessable through the MapFile.Reader API though.

The [MapFile.Reader API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/MapFile.Reader.html) also offers the method finalKey, though I'm unsure if this will be the final key in the index or that of the whole collection.